# How to get random number in the jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery plugin located at `https://github.com/tombruijn/counter.js`

but I want to show random number in this.The demo is located at

http://yipi.in

My code is as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counterUp = $("#counter-up");
    counterUp.counter({
        autoStart: true,
        duration: 21000,
        countFrom: 10,
        countTo: 2024,
        placeholder: 0,
        easing: "easeOutCubic",
        onStart: function() {
            document.getElementById("trigger").innerHTML = "Result"
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            document.getElementById("trigger").innerHTML = "Result"
        }
    });
    var counterDown = $("#counter-down");
    counterDown.counter({
        autoStart: true,
        countTo: 0,
        duration: 7000,
        easing: "easeOutCubic"
    });

    $(document).on("click", "button", function() {
        counterUp.counter("start");
        counterDown.counter("start");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: **Random + Unique = +new Date();**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Math.random function

```
var randNumber = Math.random() * 2013;
```

it will give return number between 1 to 1000;

```
  var start = 10;
  var end = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2013) + 10;

  var counterUp = $("#counter-up");
  counterUp.counter({
    autoStart: true,
    duration: 21000,
    countFrom: start,
    countTo: end,
    placeholder: 0,
    easing: "easeOutCubic",
    onStart: function() {
      document.getElementById("trigger").innerHTML = "Result"
    },
    onComplete: function() {
      document.getElementById("trigger").innerHTML = "Result"
    }
  });
  var counterDown = $("#counter-down");
  counterDown.counter({
    autoStart: true,
    countTo: 0,
    duration: 7000,
    easing: "easeOutCubic"
  });

  $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
    counterUp.counter("start");
    counterDown.counter("start");
  });
```

Comment: where should I change

Comment: Where you want to use?

Comment: Ok so you want to count form 10 to random number right?

Comment: yep I want to count from 10 to 2024 but in random order

Comment: I have updated ans 10 is fixed and 2024 will come randomly from 10 to 2024

Comment: actually this starts with 10 but ends with a random number between 10 and 2024

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93764/discussion-between-mitul-and-rohitashv-singhal).